# Prove, that two polynomials are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Please demonstrate this is true:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the expressions out and comparing them?

Comment: You can expand the right hand side and see if it is equal to the left hand side for both lines !

Comment: What makes you difficult to multiply out all right side?

Comment: @marinaaa: Please try to find a more appropriate title next time. 90% of all questions round here are about "demonstrating, that something is true".

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$1.$ $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+c^3-3abc=\{(a+b)+c\}\{(a+b)^2-(a+b)c+c^2\}-3ab(a+b+c)$$

$$=(a+b+c)\{(a+b)^2-(a+b)c+c^2-3ab\}$$

Now simplify

$2.$ $$(a+b+c)^3=(a+b)^3+c^3+3(a+b)c\{a+b+c\}$$
$$=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)+c^3+3(a+b)c\{a+b+c\}$$

$$=a^3+b^3+c^3+3ab(a+b)+3(a+b)c\{a+b+c\}$$

$$3ab(a+b)+3(a+b)c(a+b+c)=3(a+b)\{ab+c(a+b+c)\}=3(a+b)\{a(b+c)+c(b+c)\}=3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

Answer (score 1):

For polynomials (expressions computed using only sums and products) there is a canonical form which is writing them as sums of products of the variables (sums of terms) with different degree patterns.

For example $x^2+xy^3+2$ is in canonical form, while $(x+y)(x-y)$ and $x^2+y^2-y^2$ are not.

To test for equality between polynomials it is enough to write them in canonical form and compare the coefficients of the the terms with the same degree patterns. For example, to check that $(x-y)(x+y)$ is equal to $-x+x^2-y^2+x$ we can re-write them both as $x^2-y^2$, which is their canonical form.

The same applies to your problems.

For example: The left hand side of the first identity you need to prove is already in canonical form. $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ is already a sum of terms with different degree patterns. It is enough then, to re-write the right hand side in canonical form and check that it is the same. Since the right hand side is built by using only sums and products, to get to the canonical form all we need to use is the distributivity, commutativity, and associativity properties of the sum and the product.

Any product in which the factors are not just variables can be 'broken' using distributivity.

For example: $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2+xy-yx+y^2$.

This will always give you products of variables only.

Then you can group together terms with the same degree patterns. For example $xy-yx=0xy$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick I think you can use here, which can simplify checking problems like this.

The expressions you have are all symmetric in $a, b, c$. If you first set $c=0$ you get a simpler identity which involves terms in just $a, b$. This shows (by symmetry) that all the terms in just two variables are equal on both sides of the equation.

It remains then to check the terms in three variables - which here is just $abc$. This is easily enough done.

One trick way of doing the $abc$ term is to set $b=-a$ - we note that there are no terms on the left-hand side of type $a^2c$ 0r $b^2c$ - and we've already checked that there are none when the right-hand side is expanded (they are two-variable terms, so we know the two sides match) - so anything which comes out as $a^2c$ on the right-hand side must have come from an $abc$ term. This particularly helps in the second example, but takes work to notice and to check.